# AWS CoPilot pass on the environment variables/secrets defined in service manifest to the build environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, buildspec, aws-copilot

Is it possible to pass on environment variables/secrets defined in service manifest to the build environment (CodeBuild in the pipeline)?

```
variables:
  DBNAME: my_database
secrets:
  GITHUB_TOKEN: GITHUB_TOKEN
  DB_SECRET:
    secretsmanager: '${COPILOT_APPLICATION_NAME}/${COPILOT_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}/mysql'
```